# Programmatically debug excel vba module using python

Tags: python, excel, vba, pywin32

Is there a way to set a breakpoint and *programmatically* an excel vba module using `pywin32`? So far, I've been able to connect to an open instance of excel, add a workbook, add a vba module and then inject from a text file into this module.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application") # generates a com instance
excel.Visible = True
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
xlmodule = workbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

with open('test.bas') as fo:
    xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(fo.read())

print('don')
```

I'm not sure how to then go about adding a breakpoint and then debug the module line by line. I know that `XL.Application.Run` can run the module for me, but I actually want to debug it through python. Any ideas?

## Edit

Upon requests in the comments, here's my unfortunate, but nevertheless very common use case:

I have a legacy macro-enabled spreadsheet which I would like to convert to python using some form of test-driven approach. I use `pywin32` to connect to the COM representations of the modules and run them. I use `pytest` to compare against my own python-based functions to ensure I am replicating the results accurately.

The missing, yet crucial, piece is code coverage. According to [this link](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/5465) there are currently no code coverage tools for VBA modules. I need a way to circumvent this. If I can run my `pywin32` based test suite and track which lines are being run by connecting to the VBA debugger, I may be able to do some crude, albeit slow, code coverage assessments.

Comment: Curious... what's the use case for this?

Comment: @BigBen: Just my thoughts...

Comment: @BigBen please take a look at the edit to my original question. Let me know if anythings unclear

Comment: My two cents - it's highly difficult and not worth your time to attempt to do this. Acknowledge the impossible/infeasible and move on.

Comment: @BigBen how would you recommend going about it ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean....

Comment: What you're attempting to do is infeasible in my opinion / (limited) knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238708/discussion-between-user32882-and-bigben).

Comment: Checking by hand is unfortunately not an option either. This thing contains thousands of lines of code...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634957/set-breakpoint-in-vba-code-programmatically